# php variable(inside HTML form action tag) not incrementing inside of while loop despite incrementing outside form

Tags: php, html

I am producing a table that displays values from a database. when displaying values of each record, the name field I am attempting to send through the URL to the next page is not incrementing and is simply staying as the initial value set to name. i cannot see the issue as the $name variable produces no issues in incrementing outside of the form yet inside it cannot increment.

```
<?php
require_once "config.php";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM restaurant";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    echo "<table><tr><th>Name</th><th>City</th><th>Link</th></tr>";
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $name = $row["Name"];
        //$link = "<a href='info.php' >$name</a>";
        echo "<tr><td>" . $name . "</td><td>" . $row["City"] . "</td><td><form action='info.php?name=$name' method='post'><input type='submit' value='reserve now'></td></tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

mysqli_close($conn);
```

Comment: I didnt understand what's wrong with your code

Comment: the issue is in the action part of the form. the value of the $name variable inside of the URL remains the same regardless of the row it applies to despite the value of the $name tag changing in the first column of the table, I need the $name tag to change for each url

Comment: @Jayaggarwal Please, explain exactly what effect are you trying to achieve exactly.

Comment: @Jayaggarwal add a sample dump of restaurant table to see the structure and data, may be all restaurants in your database have the same value in Name column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're pasting an arbitrary text into an URL, and then paste that as an arbitrary text into HTML. That, lightly speaking, is asking for trouble.

First, glue parameter to an URL properly:

```php
$name = $row["Name"];
$action = 'info.php?name=' . urlencode($name); // This will represent special URL characters properly
```

Then, glue that to HTML properly

```php
$actionHtml = htmlentities($action); // This will represent HTML characters properly
$form = "<form action='$actionHtml' method='POST'><input type='submit' value='reserve now'/>"
```

PS: I noticed you forgot closing `</form>` in your table ;)

Comment: thanks, very helpful all fixed. first time actually making my own posts on overflow regret not using it earlier; you've been very helpful.